# Why calling method on self doesn't cause recursion in Rust?

Tags: rust

How come the code bellow doesn't cause an endless recursion?
I would expect the `impl` of `FFF` for `is_empty` calling `self.is_empty()` will cause endless recursion and not call the `impl` of `Foo`.

```rust
struct Foo{}

impl Foo{
    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> Option<bool>{
        Some(true)
    }
}

trait FFF {
    fn is_empty(&self) -> Option<bool>;
}

impl FFF for Foo {
    fn is_empty(&self) -> Option<bool>{
        println!("calling FFF");
        self.is_empty()    
    }
}

fn pr<F:FFF>(a:F){
  println!("{:?}", a.is_empty());
}

fn main() {
    pr(Foo{});
    
}
```

Output:

```
calling FFF
Some(true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method resolution always prefers inherent methods. See also [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html).

Comment: (not the OP, but interested in this): if this is the case, I would expect the OP's code to not print anything as it would call the "inherent" `is_empty` when `a.is_empty()` is executed. Instead it clearly calls the trait method, but then inside that the `self.is_empty()` calls the inherent one. This seems, well, weird to me.

Comment: @RobinZigmond that's because the first `.is_empty()` is called on value whose type is a generic type, with only a trait bound, which means all the methods will be the methods related to the trait.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Another way to explain this is that from `pr()` point of view (in its _universe_) the inherent `is_empty()` does not exist; it only knows about methods from traits.